# Preview static arrays in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there any autoexp.dat trick or whatever to make Visual Studio display static arrays (e.g. int a[4]) correctly in the Autos/Locals window?

I mean if you expand the array, it shows all the elements. But I also want the **preview** to show the elements (*similar* to std::vector).

(**Not** to be confused with the 'arr, numOfElements' trick for displaying **dynamic** arrays in the watch.)

Answer (score 0):

To view first 5 items of `std::vector v` enter this in Watch window: `v._Myfirst,5`

This works only in Debug build. Doesn't work in Release.

Comment: I already stated in my question that this is not what I'm looking for.
I want to make the preview in the Autos/Locals window show the elements.

Comment: @Trass3r please edit the question so that it is clear that you want to see items in Auto/Locals windows. Also state what version of Visual Studio you want the answer for. In Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition in Debug build I can already see the elements of `std::vector` in Auto/Locals windows.

Comment: Yes cause there is an entry for std::vector in autoexp. I want something similar for static arrays.